# Cannot reassign object key value - is my syntax incorrect?

Tags: node.js, object, syntax, promise, bcrypt

I am trying to implement a registration form using bcrypt and nodejs/express.

As you'll see below, I have tried to set `User.password = hash;` but for some reason when passing the object into postgres the unhashed password is being input.

The code below shows a minor change. I changed the original

`User.create({name, email, password})`

to

`User.create({name, email, password: hash})`

This has worked in passing in the hashed password, but doesn't make sense to me... Shouldn't this not be necessary? What am I missing?

Any help understanding what's going on would be hugely appreciated. Thanks!

```
                        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
                            if(err) throw err;
                            // Set password to hashed
                            User.password = hash;
                            console.log(hash);
                            // Save user
                            User.create({
                                name,
                                email,
                                password: hash
                            })
                                .then(user => {
                                    res.redirect('/users/login')
                                })
                                .catch(err => console.log(err));
                    }))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `User` is (I believe) a Mongoose model, similar to a class in ECMAScript 6. Directly assigning properties on the class itself (these are *static properties*) don't change the created items. What you're doing is creating a new property on the `User` variable.

So, all you need to do in order to use the shorthand property notation syntax is make a variable `password` equal to `hash`:

```
bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
  let password = hash;
  User.create(name, email, password)
    .then(user => res.redirect("/users/login"))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: This is fixed it! You are right, I was trying to adapt a mongoose code section to sequelize. This does prompt one question though if you don't mind me digging deeper: How does this not confuse the new password variable with the previously existing password key from the User object? Without your change in code, the previous password value was being passed in. Thanks!! PS: I'd like to vote you up, but it seems I don't have enough rep. Don't know enough to answer other's questions either. Sorry.

Comment: No worries @roca - if my answer fixed your problem, feel free to accept it by clicking the tick. You also gain reputation from doing this!

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `User.create({name, email, password})` is just a shortcut for:

```
User.create({
    name: name,
    email: email,
    password: password
})
```

Since your password hash is stored in the variable `hash` instead of `password` you cannot use the shortcut for it though `name` and `email` are unchanged.

In order to use the shortcut you have to store the hash in a variable named `password`:

```
bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, password) => {
                                           // ^^^ this will make it work
    if(err) throw err;
    // Set password to hashed
    User.password = password;
    console.log(password);
    // Save user
    User.create({
        name,
        email,
        password
    })
```

Comment: Just an FYI, I tried swapping out the `hash` with `password` as you mentioned, but it seems that without the `hash` being passed into the function it doesn't have anything to set `User.password = hash;` with. The error I got was `ReferenceError: hash is not defined`.

Comment: Of course, you just renamed the variable to `password` so you will have to do `User.password = password`

Comment: Do note though that if you already have a variable called `password` defined above the posted code then it is a **very bad practice** to reuse the same variable name. It is much better to call it `hash` instead and do `User.create({name, email, password:hash})`

Comment: Ah, just updated and this worked as well! Thanks!! And thanks for the tip on not reusing the same variable name as well. How does this work despite the duplication?